# how to print one value in complicated dictionary

Tags: python

I have below dictionary and I want to print 'persistentvolumeclaim "myclaim" not ' in status 
How can I print it? the dictionary is not correct I delete a lot of cod

```
{
 'api_version': 'v1',
 'kind': 'Pod',
 'metadata': {
              'annotations': None,
              'uid': 'acdad57c-7632-11e9-90cf-7c8bca006fec'
              },
 'spec': {
          'active_deadline_seconds': None,
          'containers': [
                          {
                            'args': None,     
                            'vsphere_volume': None
                          }
                        ]
         },
 'status': {
             'conditions': [
                             {
                               'last_probe_time': None,
                               'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 14, 10, 26, 3, tzinfo=tzutc()),
                               'message': 'persistentvolumeclaim "myclaim" not '
                             }
                           ]                              
             'start_time': None
           }
}
```

and this code

```
    print(dic['status']['conditions'][0]['message'])
```

get this error

```
     print(api_response['status']['conditions'][0]['message'])
        TypeError: 'V1Pod' object is not subscriptable
```

it look likes dictionary but it is not dictionary.

Comment: `print(dic['status']['conditions'][0]['message'])`

Comment: This is not valid `json`, you're missing a closing bracket `]` on `conditions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
  print(a.status.conditions[0].message)
```

it look like dictionary but it is not. it is a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect. Here is the correct JSON and print statement:

```
a = {
    'api_version': 'v1',
    'kind': 'Pod',
    'metadata': {
        'annotations': None,
        'uid': 'acdad57c-7632-11e9-90cf-7c8bca006fec'
    },
    'spec': {
        'active_deadline_seconds': None,
        'containers': [
            {
                'args': None,
                'vsphere_volume': None
            }
        ]
    },
    'status': {
        'conditions': [
            {
                'last_probe_time': None,
                'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 14, 10, 26, 3, tzinfo=tzutc()),
                'message': 'persistentvolumeclaim "myclaim" not ',
                'start_time': None
            }
        ]
    }
}

print(a['status']['conditions'][0]['message'])
```

prints:

`persistentvolumeclaim "myclaim" not`

Answer (score 0):

i finsih the conditions list in code

```
dic ={'api_version': 'v1',
 'kind': 'Pod',
 'metadata': {'annotations': None,
              'uid': 'acdad57c-7632-11e9-90cf-7c8bca006fec'},
 'spec': {'active_deadline_seconds': None,
          'containers': [{'args': None,

                       'vsphere_volume': None}]},
 'status': {'conditions': [{'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 14, 10, 26, 3, tzinfo=tzutc()),
                            'message': 'persistentvolumeclaim "myclaim" not '}],
            'start_time': None}}

print(dic['status']['conditions'][0]['message']) 

# output persistentvolumeclaim "myclaim" not
```